# Closure Compiler API

Tags: php, curl, google-closure-compiler

http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-ref.html

I don't understand how to pass multiple `code_url` parameters (multiple files to compress)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [python tutorial](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial2.html) uses multiple parameters with the same name. You probably can do the same with the tools or language you are using.

```
params = urllib.urlencode([
   # Multiple code_url parameters:
   ('code_url', 'http://yourserver.com/yourJsPart1.js'),
   ('code_url', 'http://yourserver.com/yourJsPart2.js'),
   ('compilation_level', 'WHITESPACE_ONLY'),
   ('output_format', 'text'),
   ('output_info', 'compiled_code'),
 ])
```

Comment: Can't do this with PHP. If I add another code_url argument, it simply overwrites the previous one..

Comment: When creating a parameter array use another array to hold multiple values: `$params["code_url"][] = $url1; $params["code_url"][] = $url1;`

Comment: Is there any way of doing this with javascript?
If I create an obj like:
`obj = {code_url: 'path/script1.js', code_url: 'path/script2.js'}`
the variable will only get the last value (duplicate keys)